# Функции для обновления скрипта через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: скрипт, php, функции

Подскажите, какие есть функции в php для обновления скрипта через определённый промежуток времени? 
В общем есть скрипт, который мониторит статус сервера. Как сделать, чтоб при встраивании на сайт он обновлялся ну например раз в 5 секунд)

Comment: А что значит "способы обновления скрипта"? Конкретизируйте задачу, плиззз.

Comment: окей))))))

Comment: Хм... После вашего уточнения совсем стало грустно )) Может вы имели в виду то, как запускать скрипт каждые 5 сек. для мониторинга? Тогда вам надо познакомиться с такой вещью, как **Cron**

Comment: а как сделать не кроном а php?

Comment: @kravasuper, вы же, я так понимаю, ищете достаточно простой способ? Так почему же Cron вам не подходит? На платных хостингах, в панели управления (cPanel, DirectAdmin и т.д.), есть элементарный способ добавить задание: прописываете путь к вашему файлу, указываете рассписание, по которому надо его запускать и спокойно идете на пиво.))

Comment: я знаю как пользоваться cronom, но я та спрашиваю про php

Comment: Тогда может [эта статья](http://neverlex.com/cat/programming/starting-the-script-without-cron/) вам поможет

Answer (score 1):

«при встраивании на сайт» – на сайт кто-нибудь заходит, или это неизвестный пустой ресурс? Тогда у скрипта нет шансов запуститься, ведь НИЧЕГО не происходит, а cron вы не хотите.

В WordPress есть wp-cron, который запускается каждый раз, как кто-то заходит на сайт, и смотрит, сколько времени прошло с его предыдущего запуска. Если больше, чем X, то этот псевдо-крон запускает свои задачи. Таков сценари по умолчанию. На нагруженных проектах рекомендуется отключать эту схему, и запускать wp-cron.php из настоящего крона по расписанию, чтобы не проверять при каждом из 1000 запросов в секунду, пора уже что-то сделать, или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

JS

```
    function updateInfo(){ 
      var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
      var obj = document.getElementById('res_div');
      var type = "GET|POST";
      xhr.open(type,"time.php");
      if (type=="POST") xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
              obj.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
           }
      }

      xhr.send();

 }

    setInterval(updateInfo(),5000);
```

JS (Альтернативный)

```
setInterval(window.location.reload(),5000);
```

AJAX

```
function show()  
        {  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "time.php",  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#content").html(html);  
                }  
            });  
        }  

        $(document).ready(function(){  
            show();  
            setInterval('show()',1000);  
        });
```

HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Средставами РНР это сделать просто нельзя. Тем более, если Вам необходимо обновить только часть страницы, а не одну страницу.